# Can't change files with Transmit through SFTP. Wrong permissions

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, sftp

I'm having an Ubuntu Server installation. In a folder deployed a wordpress installation and because of the file uploads, plugin updates etc I chowned the entire folder and its subdirectories to www-data:www-data (apache). I have a username, lets say **hambos22**. I added my username to www-data group, and now when i'm trying to SFTP to that folder through Transmit I can't change or modify files. It says that I don't have the right permissions to do it. I disabled the root login for security reasons as meny articles recommended.

My question is: Can I login with "sudo" through Transmit? Or maybe another workaround? I tried various methods like chowned user->hambos22 group->www-data, which works only for SFTP, but no for the wordpress automatic updates and file uploads

Comment: You could change the permissions to `g+w`, so your username will be able to write them.

Comment: You could create an extra user with the same uid as www-data. Or why not login as www-data itself? Or why not chown everything to hambos22 and have the webserver run as hambos22 as well?